# MySQL - Many to One and sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the following MySQL query which pulls together the data I want:

```
select
b.id AS id,
b.sqloc AS BL_SQLOC,
b.locname AS BL_LOCNAME,
b.sql1 AS BL_SQL1,
b.sql2 AS BL_SQL2,
b.sql3 AS BL_SQL3,
b.sql4 AS BL_SQL4,
b.sql5 AS BL_SQL5,
u.sqloc AS SQLOC,
GROUP_CONCAT(u.unit) AS UNITS

FROM block b,
units u

WHERE
u.sqloc = b.sqloc

group by b.sqloc

ORDER BY LENGTH(b.sqloc), b.sqloc, u.units
```

For each `BLOCK` there are several `UNITS`. I am doing a 'natural' sort which is why I'm using `length` in the sort.

When I sort by `BLOCK` first, it sorts by block but not `UNITS`

When I sort by `UNITS` first, it sorts by units but not `BLOCKS`

I'm not sure how to resolve this.

**EXAMPLE**

This is what I'd like to end up with:

```
Block      Units
 1         02424, 24578, 34443
 2         39625, 45624, 55512
 5         25624, 35624, 55527
10         02684, 12224, 89881
12         39821, 40001, 80062
```

Comment: would you post an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregated rows can be ordered separately and then `u.unit` is not required any more in the outer `order by`.

```
SELECT
  b.id AS id,
  b.sqloc AS BL_SQLOC,
  b.locname AS BL_LOCNAME,
  b.sql1 AS BL_SQL1,
  b.sql2 AS BL_SQL2,
  b.sql3 AS BL_SQL3,
  b.sql4 AS BL_SQL4,
  b.sql5 AS BL_SQL5,
  u.sqloc AS SQLOC,
  GROUP_CONCAT(u.unit ORDER BY u.unit ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS UNITS
FROM
  block b,
  units u
WHERE
  u.sqloc = b.sqloc
GROUP BY
  b.sqloc
ORDER BY
  LENGTH(b.sqloc),
  b.sqloc
```